# Primes that are sums of two squares with constraints on the squares

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, sums-of-squares

It is well known that there are infinitely many primes of the form $a^2+b^2$ (namely all primes congruent to $1$ modulo $4$). On the other hand, Euler raised the problem as to whether there are infinitely many primes of the form $a^2+1$, which is still open (a positive answer is a special case of Bunyakovsky's conjecture). I am wondering whether there are known results in between these cases.

To be precise, I am interested in the following problem: Are there infinitely many primes $p$ of the form $a^2+b^2$ such that $b$ is bounded by a (slowly growing) function of $p$, for example $b = o(\sqrt{p})$?

Comment: There is a result (someone else will recall the reference) on primes of the form x^4 + y^2  (Friedlander and Iwaniec?).  The result may even say how large the squares are in relation to one another.  Gerhard "Relying On The Collective Memory" Paseman, 2015.02.13

Comment: The title of http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1103-15.pdf appears relevant, but I do not speak Japanese.

Comment: @David Speyer: it's pretty thrilling to get such a reference less than one week before I take the N3 level of the Japanese Language Proficiency Test!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Hecke](https://eudml.org/doc/167556) showed that there are infinitely many primes of the form $p=a^2+b^2$ with $a = o(\sqrt{p})$. [Ankeny](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372233) improved this to $o(\log p)$, conditional on the Extended Riemann Hypothesis. [Harman and Lewis](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FMTK%2FMTK48_1-2%2FS0025579300014388a.pdf&code=c830294987d83b3d7fc0936b8a4b398c) obtain $o(p^{0.119})$ unconditionally. (Disclaimer: I copied the Hecke reference from Ankeny's bibliography without checking it.) The latter two papers cite other related work.

I'd like to point out that I am not an expert here -- this was the result of googling

> "Gaussian prime" angle

and then chasing references through MathSciNet and ResearchGate.